# Averaging the last few entries of every unique value in a column to generate new df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, pandas-groupby

I have a `df.head()` of my data frame looks like this. I'm measuring my data somewhere between 7 and 9 Hz frequency and have about 100 unique values of `Psnr`. If I want to create a new data frame with one point representing the averaged value of the last five minutes of each unique `Psnr`, what is the best way to do so?

```
Datum_Zeit  Psnr
2018-10-04 14:43:11.410 2
2018-10-04 14:43:11.600 2
2018-10-04 14:43:11.790 2
2018-10-04 14:43:11.970 2
2018-10-04 14:43:12.160 2
```

A possible way of doing this is creating sub-data frames, filtering and merging them again, like below. But, I am sure that there must be an easier solution

```
dfs = {k: df[df['Psnr'] == k] for k in df['Psnr'].unique()}
```

Comment: I see all values in 'Psnr' column are unique so I do not understand how they can be the same. Additionaly, what is the last character '2' ?or maybe Psnr = 2 and HH:MM:SS is part of Datum_Zeit?

Comment: Yes, Psnr=2,3,4...to 100. HH:MM:SS is included in the Datum_Zeit. I parsed dates with the two columns when I imported my csv files to generate it.

Comment: @hegdep - What is expected output? Mean of datetimes?

Comment: @jezarel Mean of many columns, I will update the data in a bit

Comment: @hegdep - You can check my solution - added 2 new columns with changed solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need first filter last 5 minutes data for each group and then aggregate `mean` by column `Psnr`:

```
print (df)
                Datum_Zeit  Psnr  Speed  Torque
0  2018-10-04 14:38:11.410     2      8       6
1  2018-10-04 14:39:11.600     2      7       0
2  2018-10-04 14:40:11.790     2      1       1
3  2018-10-04 14:41:11.970     2      9       3
4  2018-10-04 14:43:12.160     2      5       1
5  2018-10-04 14:39:11.600     3      7       0
6  2018-10-04 14:40:11.790     3      1       1
7  2018-10-04 14:44:11.970     3      9       3
8  2018-10-04 14:45:12.160     3      5       1

df['Datum_Zeit'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datum_Zeit'])

s = df.groupby('Psnr')['Datum_Zeit'].transform('max')
df = df[df['Datum_Zeit'].between(s - pd.Timedelta(300, 's'), s)]
print (df)
               Datum_Zeit  Psnr  Speed  Torque
1 2018-10-04 14:39:11.600     2      7       0
2 2018-10-04 14:40:11.790     2      1       1
3 2018-10-04 14:41:11.970     2      9       3
4 2018-10-04 14:43:12.160     2      5       1
7 2018-10-04 14:44:11.970     3      9       3
8 2018-10-04 14:45:12.160     3      5       1
```

If need mean of all columns without `datetime`:

```
df = df.groupby('Psnr').mean()
print (df)
      Speed  Torque
Psnr               
2       5.5    1.25
3       7.0    2.00
```

If need column of datetime column only:

```
df['dates']= df['Datum_Zeit'].astype(np.int64)
df1 = pd.to_datetime(df.groupby('Psnr')['dates'].mean()).reset_index()
print (df1)
   Psnr                         dates
0     2 2018-10-04 14:40:56.880000000
1     3 2018-10-04 14:44:42.064999936
```

Comment: What if I have many more columns? Like a 100 and not just the two?

Comment: @hegdep - Not sure if understand, can you explian more? It is mean of datetimes? Or not?

Comment: Instead of two columns, what if I have more columns, like `speed`, `torque`, `moment of inertia`, etc.. ?

Comment: @hegdep - Can you change data sample? e.g 2 groups with more columns and expected output?

Comment: @hegdep - added more data with 2 groups, please check edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since your dataframe is already sorted by time you can calculate a `min_time` series aligned with your dataframe index via `transform` + `last`, then filter and finally `groupby`:

```
min_times = df.groupby('Psnr')['Datum_Zeit'].transform('last') - pd.Timedelta('5 min')

res = df.loc[df['Datum_Zeit'] > min_times]\
        .groupby('Psnr').mean().reset_index()

print(res)

   Psnr  Speed  Torque
0     2    5.5    1.25
1     3    7.0    2.00
```